# Google Appengine external cassandra ImportError: No module named cassandra.cluster

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, cassandra, datastax, google-app-engine-python

Trying to use an externally hosted Cassandra server from standard environment appengine (development environment). I see this error:

```
  "..main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cassandra.cluster
  "..google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 964, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named cassandra.cluster
```

**main.py**

```
import cassandra

# this works ... prints 3.9.0
print cassandra.__version__

# all these variations fail with import error
import cassandra.cluster               
# from cassandra.cluster import Cluster 
# from cassandra import cluster

# this works
import cassandra.metrics
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

**appengine_config.py**

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```

**Folder structure**

```
app.yaml
appengine_config.py
main.py
lib
  |-cassandra
       |-cluster.py
       |-.....
  |-concurrent
  |-six
```

- All modules installed with `pip install -t lib/ cassandra-driver`
- importing cassandra.metrics works indicating the paths seem ok

Any help appreciated.

Comment: post the contents of `appengine_config.py`

Comment: try `from cassandra import cluster`

Comment: What's the output of `print cassandra.__path__` ? And you can't run the modules having c extensions..

Comment: ok, then try `import cassandra` and in the code use `cassandra.cluster`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142689/discussion-between-fakeer-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting on [sandbox.py, line 964](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-compat-runtime/blob/master/appengine-compat/exported_appengine_sdk/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py#L964) shows it is thrown from within an import hook implementing a C module.  Avinash Raj already pointed out that you "can't run the modules having c extensions", something that is clearly [documented](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime#Python_Introduction):

> The interpreter cannot load Python modules with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment.

Even though cassandra driver, supports a [no-cython installation](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html#cython-based-extensions):

```
pip install -t lib/ --install-option="--no-cython" cassandra-driver
```

... going this path will make us hit a second issue with [Python Standard Library's fcntl module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mroman/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/mroman/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/mroman/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/mroman/tmp/cassandra_importError/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import asyncore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 608, in <module>
    import fcntl
  File "/home/mroman/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 964, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named fcntl
```

It seems this module is not whitelisted as it performs file control and I/O control on file descriptors and AppEngine's restricted "sandbox" doesn't allow apps to write to the filesystem.

I've checked other Cassandra drivers like:

- [telephus](https://github.com/driftx/Telephus) : It is based on Twisted so will also not work because ["Async IO (such as Twisted in Python) is not supported"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/)
- [pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa): Older version of cassandra-driver. Might work though I doubt it.

Because of all of the above, I believe your only options would be:

- Set up a REST interface in front of your Cassandra database
- Use [App Engine Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for doing the research. So basically dead in the water. Any idea about the PHP driver? If that works then at least I can run it as a module and build an api within appengine standard environment.

Comment: Datastax PHP driver for Cassandra also has C extensions so that's no workaround. I'd suggest going GAE Flexible.

Comment: Flex is not an option right now. Have to check on  two remaining possibilities - java or Go